# Proper way to export intent action

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there a proper way to public describe/declare broadcasted intents for others?

For example I have an application that broadcasts informations with the help of intents. Another application wants to use these intents in a broadcast reciever. How does the other application gets to know what the intent provides?

I'am now looking on how to publicly document the intent with its action name, extras. I have something like the Eclipse extension point description in mind. Any suggestion?

---

Additional reading: [Things that cannot change](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html)

Comment: Is your issue solved or do you need further assistance? Is there anything I can add to my answer to further help you?

Comment: @XaverKapeller Well, I just hoped that there are other opinions about this topic. As even mainting action/extra names in multiproject builds is a pain...But it seems there is nothing I can do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the required constants somewhere, for example in the `Service` or `BroadcastReceiver` which handles those, and if you want you can write java doc to describe each field:

```
public class SomeService extends IntentService {

    /**
     *  Used to tell the {@link com.example.SomeService} to display a notification 
     */
    public static final String ACTION_NOTIFICATION = NotificationService.class.getName() + "_ACTION_NOTIFICATION";

    /**
     *  An Intent extra for the id of a reminder. Used by {@link at.medmedia.copaxone.service.NotificationService#ACTION_NOTIFICATION}
     */
    public static final String EXTRA_REMINDER_ID = NotificationService.class.getName() + "EXTRA_REMINDER_ID";

    ...    
}
```

The `SomeService.class.getName()` is used to prefix all constants. This ensures (with a high probability) that those constants have a unique `String` value. It can be very important that those values are unique if your library or framework is used by third party apps.

People which are using your library can then construct the `Intents` without any problem:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SomeService.class);
intent.setAction(SomeService.ACTION_NOTIFICATION);
intent.putExtra(SomeService.EXTRA_REMINDER_ID, reminder.getId());
startService(intent);
```

Aside from that I wouldn't worry about it. If people want to interact with your app/library/whatever they just need to know how. You can make the coding itself easy and less painful by defining the constants like above, but the other developer still has to know what he is doing, so he/she will look at a guide or tutorial (preferable something you provide) to learn what he/she needs to know.

If you want you can also define all those constants in one Java file and provide a separate download link just for that.

Comment: Thats the way I'm doing it right now. In this way I have to have a compile-time-reference  to the broadcasting-project or use plain strings. Neither is so nice. But it seems the only option is that the recieving client has to ensure correct intent-filters and parsing of extras (in case the broadcasting-project is updated)

Comment: Yes it is the responsibility of the developer of the third party app to get it right. Just be sure you documented everything properly.